# how to make gridview element clickable using jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to click the one of the element of gridview using jQuery click function.

Gridview bind using jQuery:

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var customers = xml.find("Table");
                var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
                $.each(customers, function () {
                    var customer = $(this);
                    //$("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("TDC_NO").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").text($(this).find("TDC_NO").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").attr("href","Uncoated_Wire.aspx?Id=" + $(this).find("TDC_NO").text()).attr('target','_blank');
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("REVISION").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("REVISION_DATE").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("P_GROUP").text());
                    $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
                    row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });
            }
```

I want this line

```
$("td", row).eq(0).find("a").attr("href","Uncoated_Wire.aspx?Id=" + $(this).find("TDC_NO").text()).attr('target','_blank');
```

to be clickable like jquery

```
$("#TFile").click(function (event) { 
  ///
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `$("td", row).eq(0).find("a").attr("href","Uncoated_Wire.aspx?Id=" + $(this).find("TDC_NO").text()).attr('target','_blank').on('click',function() { console.log("clicked") })`

Comment: @Tibrogargan i tried like this $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").attr("href", "Uncoated_Wire.aspx?Id=" + $(this).find("TDC_NO").text()).attr('target', '_blank').on('c‌​lick', function () { alert("clicked"); });   also but it also not worked